# Do fallen leaves produce oxygen?

Tags: botany, photosynthesis

After a leaf has fallen from a tree, if it is still green and hasn't dried out, is it still converting CO<sub>2</sub> into O<sub>2</sub> if not put in water?

Can anyone find any data showing how long any different species of leaf will continue to produce oxygen after fallen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**
It all depends on the time window you are talking about. After having been detached from the mother plant, a leaf will typically keep on photosynthesizing for a few hours or so.

**Background**
Cutting of the stalk of the leaf results in impaired water flow and wilting. As soon as a leaf is detached from the plant, it will also be cut off from hormones, minerals and other nutrients. The result of this is that senescence (and death) sets in straight away. However, leaves will typically stay green and moist for hours or even days, dependent on the conditions it is stored. Hence, in practice, photosynthesis can be measures at least a few hours after a typical leaf is picked (source: [Science and Plants for Schools](http://www.saps.org.uk/saps-associates/browse-q-and-a/316-will-a-leaf-photosynthesise-if-no-longer-attached-to-the-plant-and-if-so-how-long-for)).

Comment: Thanks so much. Any more-detailed information showing exactly how long they will continue to photosynthesize?

Comment: @Johan88 - depends on species, and conditions (heat, humidity and so forth)

Comment: that's exactly what I'm thinking, but I hope I can get some data from some studies, but have not been able to find any such studies.

Comment: It would be a nice experiment to use CO_2 with radioactive C14 isotope in an artificial atmosphere to measure it, or you can measure the increase of humidity (much easier, but less crazy scientisty and accurate). btw. the saddest biology question ever :( poor leaves...

Comment: Note that there are many plants where if you cut off some part of it and leave it lying on the ground, it will grow roots and become a new plant.

Comment: @atevm Hahaha. The saddest Biology question Kakaka. Well, the leaves fall around me all the time, and I like to pick them up and put them in a bowl in the hopes they can still create oxygen for a while and their life isn't over yet  :)

Comment: @Johan88, seriously, you are not kidding?  There is plenty of O2 and as long as things like CO2 concentrations stay stable or better RISE in ppm plants and the ocean will continually make O2.  There are far better ways to expend your energies!

Comment: Every single thing that was once alive, once dead, once cut off begins to decompose immediately.  Fully is the temperature is correct.  O2 is produced during the day as long as there is CO2, tiny tiny amounts of chemistry (NOT NUTRIENTS), water, drainage in the soil medium, ventilation...actively photosynthesizing chlorophyll produces oxygen, 'sinking' the CO2 within its biomass.  Just like the ocean.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrrSAc-vjG4 This would be fun for you to watch if you've not watched already.  When they say the words, 'food for plants' I want you to hear me scream!!  Otherwise, great documentary.

Comment: @stormy truth be told, I'm not allowed to bring plants where I work: boss would consider it inappropriate. Modern decor: the air REEKS of plastic and fumes and I absolutely hate it and feel nauseous. I pick up fallen leaves in the morning and stuff them where they have some light and won't be seen. Hope it improves oxygen. Certainly has a placebo effect if it doesn't. Need some damn green! :P I dump em when they're dried out since decomposition does the opposite I think: O2 to CO2

Comment: Ah, Johan, you are describing a true nightmare.  Decomposing leaves don't provide oxygen.  The smell of earth, of rot and decay, 'centers' you.  Something like that. Sigh and major sigh.  I would be working on a major change for you...I hate money. Anyway, You need to get your hands in the dirt after and before work.  You need to 'work out'...cardiovascular mostly.  Walking, running, bicycling.  That will help you keep your objectivity.  I get it, I do!  You are the only one who decides the directions of your life.  You be honest with you and take care of you firstus!

Comment: @stormy Thanks. When I said "Need some green" I meant need some green life, plants, even if it's just a few leaves I pluck each day, despite my modern square plastic concrete boss and her rules. Lol, she caught a sight of a small leaf pile the other day and was like, "What's that?" "It's my oxygen machine. Cannot?" "Really?" "Cannot?" *"REALLY?"* "The air quality is so bad. Cannot?" "Get rid of it on your lunch break." Currently I'm hiding an airplant somewhere. Lol. Good things my boss's boss likes me, otherwise my little quirks would not be tolerated.

Comment: Johann...it is nice your boss likes you, needs you.  You sound as if you need to be self employed.  Photosynthesis produces oxygen but there is plenty of it around, you don't need to make anymore.  Decomposition doesn't produce O2 it uses it during aerobic decomposition.  You are so dang cute.  Hiding an air plant.  Seriously, life is too wonderful to waste a single minute working FOR someone else in an environment that is driving you nuts.  Huggs.  You and your little quirks need to find a new home where appreciated!

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rien_Aerts/publication/216809762_Climate_Leaf_Litter_Chemistry_and_Leaf_Litter_Decomposition_in_Terrestrial_Ecosystems_A_Triangular_Relationship/links/54412b640cf2e6f0c0f60201.pdf

Comment: @stormy self employment is the plan. In HK, in the heart of the city, kilometers of concrete and asphalt all around me in every direction, air pollution is terrible. I want the plants for air cleaning (fumes and chemicals) more then oxygen. My boss doesn't like me. She fears me. Because her boss fears me. Because the former boss of the boss of my boss loves me. It's complicated. I'm aiming to launch my own business. I'm not against hierarchy at all, in principle. The problem is toxic personalities when you encounter them. And I want to employ people below me, and be a great boss. Thankyou hug!

Comment: You said the magic words, "they fear you"....this is a good thing as well as very bad.  If you are unable to get support, you've been boycotted.  Try to become less visible.  Less, grins, scary?  You will have to lead, and the more experience you've had with other humans the better a leader you will be.  Toxic personalities is not a helpful perspective.  As a leader you will be making these 'toxic' people into productive happy people, all part of a team.  Objectivity is a crucial skill. Sit down or lie down and imagine where you want to live and how you want to affect the world around you.